# Global Variable in Swift

Tags: swift, global-variables, xcode6

I'm creating an iOS 8 app and I want to create a string variable that is accessible to all class. I tried to create `global.swift` with a string variable in it. I can access the variable but, everytime I initialize the class again using this line `let globalVar = global()` the value that I've passed returns a nil value. Can someone help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the variable in your AppDelegate, which is a singleton. See this post for how to access the AppDelegate

[How do I get a reference to the app delegate in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046164/how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-the-app-delegate-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
public static var global = "String"
```

in any class. Access via Classname.global.

Answer (score 0):

Just use your `Global.swift` file and put your global variables and functions inside without any class around it.

```
//
//  Global.swift
// 

let myConstant = 5

func myGlobalFunction() {
    // ...
}
```

You can access those variables and functions all around your module.