# Ho to get a reference to appdelegate from Swift in a mixed application (primary language ObjC) to avoid reference loop

Tags: objective-c, swift, appdelegate

First of all I know about this: [How do I get a reference to the app delegate in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046164/how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-the-app-delegate-in-swift)

Second, what I need to do is to access the appdelegate properties in the Swift side of a mixed app.

Basically,
1- I have a project which is started as an Objective C project. This means AppDelegate is defined in the Objective C side.
2- I have swift code working fine, I have a bridge header and I can reference things form either side on the other side.
3- **Here is the problem:**  To reference the appdelegate in my Swift code I need to `#import "AppDelegate.h"` in my bridging header. But for other reasons, I also need the AppDelegate.h to import the SWift header ( `PROJECT-Swift.h` ). This creates a reference loop.

Is there a way to avoid this reference loop? and still access AppDelegate properties?

EDIT: An additional complication that I did not mention in the first edition of the question is that, the AppDelegate property that I want to expose to Swift code, is actually of a Type declared in the Swift side. So I need to declare it in the `AppDelegate.h` and to be able to do that, I need to import the `-Swift.h` header in my `AppDelegate.h`.
To make it more clear:
`KB` is a `public class` defined on the Swift side.
AppDelegate has a property like: `@property (strong) KB *appkb;` 
I need to get a hold of `((AppDelegate*)UIApplication.SharedApplication()).appkb`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should import `PROJECT-Swift.h` in `AppDelegate.m`, not `.h`

In `AppDelegate.h`, you can use "forward declaration" (`@class` and `@protocol`) like:

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SwiftClass;
@class KB;
@protocol SwiftProtocol;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<SwiftProtocol> swifter;
@property (strong, nonatomic) KB *appkb;

-(void)methodReceiveSwiftClass:(SwiftClass *)obj;

//...

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "PROJECT-Swift.h"

@implemetation AppDelegate

//....

@end
```

PROJECT-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

Any.swift:

```
@objc public protocol SwiftProtocol {
    // ...
}

@objc public class SwiftClass:NSObject {
    // ...
}

@objc public class KB:NSObject {
    // ...
}
```

[The document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_86) says:

> To avoid cyclical references, don’t import Swift into an Objective-C header file. Instead, you can forward declare a Swift class to use it in an Objective-C header. Note that you cannot subclass a Swift class in Objective-C.

Comment: Thank you, that will definitely work for some situations. In my case, the AppDelegate property that I want to expose to Swift code, is actually of of Type declared in the Swift side. So I need to declare it in the `AppDelegate.h` and to be able to do that, I need to import the `-Swift.h` header in my `AppDelegate.h` right?

Comment: I saw your edited question, but still, I think `@class KB;` in `AppDelegate.h` should works. Did you actually tried that?