# Accessing App Delegate from XCTestCase Subclass - Wrong Type?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I am just getting into unit testing in Xcode, so I decided to play a bit with the default test target that gets created with any of Xcode's project templates.

As a start, I decided to perform a very basic test to see whether the `AppDelegate` instance's `window` property (of type `UIWindow?`) is actually set.

This is my test code:

```
import UIKit
import XCTest

import Sample   // This is the App target (app is called "Sample")

class SampleTests: XCTestCase
{
    override func setUp(){
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    override func tearDown(){
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testExample(){
        // This is an example of a functional test case.

        if let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate{

            if let myDelegate = delegate as? AppDelegate {

                if let window = myDelegate.window {

                    XCTAssert(true, "Pass")
                }
                else{
                    XCTFail("App Delegate Has No Window")
                }
            }
            else{
                XCTFail("Application Delegate Object Is of The Wrong Type")
            }
        }
        else{
            XCTFail("Application Delegate Not Present")
        }
    }
}
```

At first, I couldn't build the test target because the AppDelegate class was not accessible. I tried two approaches, with different results:

1. If I mark both my `AppDelegate` class and all its properties/methods as public, **the test builds with no errors and succeeds** (i.e., `window` optional is not `nil`).
2. If, instead, I mark class, properties and methods of AppDelegate as `internal`, but modify the source file's target membership to also belong to the test target (not just the app target), **the test builds with no errors but fails** ("Application Delegate Object Is of The Wrong Type", i.e., the conditional cast to `AppDelegate` type **fails**).

Looks as though with the second approach, a different application delegate is present at runtime. Does anybody know what is happening?

Comment: actually there is different app delegate for your project and for your test project....

Comment: @Nicolas anish is right, check rintaro's answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946677/uiapplication-sharedapplication-delegate-as-appdelegate-causes-exc-bad-access

Comment: @Bhushan I guess that means my question is a duplicate. Exact same problem, exact same solution. Still not very clear on why  AppName.AppDelegate and AppNameTests.AppDelegate are different classes, but I guess that's how the test runtime environment is set up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a single App Delegate file in the project.But when you add AppDelegate.swift to the tests target members,then your Test's App Delegate Class will be different than the AppDelegate class.

```
 if let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate{
```

The above `If` statement tries to returns project delegate instance different than you are trying to **Cast**.

```
   if let myDelegate = delegate as? AppDelegate
```

And hence casting to `AppDelegate` doesnot succeed.So,you get always fail as

```
 XCTFail("Application Delegate Object Is of The Wrong Type")
```

**UPDATED:**

i wrote some few test cases to know the exact problem:

1)Test Case to find out if AppDelegate is nil. (Passes)

```
 if let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate{

            XCTAssertNotNil(delegate, "not nil")
```

2)So,next test is below (Fails)

```
XCTAssertNotNil(delegate as? AppDelegate, "not nil")
```

This test case fails..So its sure there was problem in casting.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was suspecting. However, the wording of your answer doesn't make clear _why_. The answer pointed to by @Bhushan contains a more illumintaing sentence: "When you do that, AppName.AppDelegate and AppNameTests.AppDelegate becomes different classes.".

Comment: actually i too hit few test cases as of updated answer and concluded what was wrong..i  will update the answer later on...

Comment: Thanks again. I have accepted your answer, but also marked my question as duplicate. Feel free to add any further information to your answer,