# Core Data, with Swift. Entity query

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am presently making my first steps using Core Data, with Swift.
Even though I have quite a bit of experience with Core Data, I have close to none with Swift.

Here is what I want to do: make a function which is going to compute the number of records in an entity, from the name of the entity.

Something like this:

```
func countEntity (name:String) -> Int {
    var theNumberOfRecords:Int
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:name)
    // What I have tried at this point only gives error messages …..
    return theNumberOfRecords
}
```

It should not be rocket science. But I have not been able to make something work after various trial and errors.
How should I write the necessary code? I presume it should be no more that a few lines. The one I have in Objective C is 6 lines.

Comment: If you want to write a lot fewer lines of code, try using https://github.com/Prosumma/CoreDataQueryInterface. Your query would be something like `managedObjectContext.from(Entity).filter({$0.name == name}).count()` and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the number of objects a fetch request would have returned
with `countForFetchRequest()`:

```
func countEntity (name:String, context : NSManagedObjectContext) -> Int {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:name)
    var error : NSError?
    let theNumberOfRecords = context.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)
    if theNumberOfRecords == NSNotFound {
        println("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
    return theNumberOfRecords
}
```

In the case of an error, `countForFetchRequest()` returns
`NSNotFound` and you have to decide how to handle that situation.

Comment: Thanks. When writing what you suggest. I first get a complaint asking for a ! after `context`
After fixing this, I have no error.
But then, when I try to call this function (which I have placed in `AppDelegate`) from the `RootViewController` I get an error saying:
`Cannot invoke 'countEntity' with an argument list of type '(String)'`
I don’t quite understand why, but I suppose I must be making some beginner mistake.
Am I not missing the equivalent of "#import AppDelegate.h" in objective C, if that ever exists?

Comment: @Michel: I changed the signature of the function so that it must be called as `countEntity("YourEntityName", context)`. Does the RootViewController have a pointer to the managed object context? How did you do it in Objective-C? Perhaps something like `let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!` is what you are looking for, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/24046979/1187415.

Comment: I saw that, but I do not think this is the issue, because I kept the old signature. The RootViewController not having a pointer to the managed object context, I use the local one already inside AppDelegate. This is what I always did in ObjC. But how can RootViewController know about the proper signature for a function somewhere else?
Since there is no "#import AppDelegate.h" like thing? I am missing some detail.

Comment: Following what is in the link you just mentioned. I was able to make it work, with both your signature and mine. It seems like I need a bit of practice in Swift:)