# swift override appdelegate method in other viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I have written a function in Appdelegate. I want to override this function in ViewcontrollerA , ViewcontrollerB. Because same method has different behaviour in ViewcontrollerA , ViewcontrollerB.

How to call this function in Viewcontroller, I don't understand.

**Update**

```
class NaviBarVC: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}

func click_save() {



}
}


class ViewcontrollerA: NaviBarVC {

override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad() }

override func click_save() { // Error 
super.click_save()

    }

 }
```

Comment: I don't think "override" is the word you are looking for. Your view controllers are surely not subclasses of your app delegate?

Comment: If you want to **call** a method of your app delegate **from** your view controllers, use something like this: `if let appDelegate = UIApplication.delegate as? AppDelegate {
    appDelegate.myMethod() // change to your actual method
}`

Comment: Make a BaseViewController and write your method in that instead of AppDelegate and then inherit ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB from the BaseViewController. Then you can override that method.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046164/how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-the-app-delegate-in-swift

Comment: Write method() in extension of UIViewController then it is possible to override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot override that `AppDelegate` method. As ViewController heirarchy doesn't have it's superclass as AppDelegate. It inherits from `UIViewController`. So if you want to override, you have to create a viewController class and from this class you can override that method by inheriting

Like this----

```
 class BaseViewController : UIViewController{

func yourMethod(){
   }

}
```

Now, class which overrides this method will be like this

```
class YourController : BaseViewController{

override func yourMethod(){
super.yourMethod()
// write your code here

   }
}
```

And yes if you just want to access the method of AppDelegate and don't want to override it. You can do like this.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.yourMethod()
```

Comment: @swiftuser123 did you got it?

Comment: I tried your answer, but it says method does not override method from its super class. check my updated question for code.

Comment: @swiftuser123 Check my updated answer. Sorry your `class YourController : UIViewController` will be `class YourController : BaseViewController`. Edited your code in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override function that declare in AppDelegate but you can access function that added in AppDelegate by use of declare global variable.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

and you can access AppDelegate's property anywhere in any viewController by

```
appDelegate.yourFuncName...()
```

Comment: But i want to change its behaviour in my Viewcontroller, is it not possible?

Comment: Actually I have created my own Navigationbar in Appdelegate, because I want this navigation bar to be present in every viewcontroller. Save button in this navigation bar has an action. I want to call this save function in other viewcontrollers and save different values as per viewcontroller.

Answer (score -1):

make class method in AppDelegate.h

```
   @interface
   +(AppDelegate*)Getdelegate;
   -(void)testfunction;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
+(AppDelegate*)Getdelegate
 {
   return (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
  }
```

in ViewControllerA

```
  [[AppDelegate Getdelegate] testFunction];
```

Comment: Question is Swift