# How do I access the UIApplicationDelegate from any particular view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

**Scenario:**
I want to set a boolean flag within the App Delegate that is accessible from a view controller.

How do I access this flag from any View Controller?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a reference to the app delegate in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046164/how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-the-app-delegate-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "within the AppDelegate", do you mean as an instance property? If the app delegate class is AppDelegate, then the instance of it is `UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate`, and any instance properties it may have can be access through that reference.

But if you simply mean "in the file *AppDelegate.swift* but outside the AppDelegate class itself", then this variable is a global and can be accessed directly from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You simply create the flag inside your delegate and access it like this:

> let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate