# Calling Objective-C from Swift -> Cannot find type 'AppDelegate' in scope

Tags: swift, objective-c

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046164/how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-the-app-delegate-in-swift) and I believe my problem is different.

I have a swift class `SwiftUtils.swift` that is already making calls to objective c code in my project and I have some objective c code making calls back to swift.

So I've got the bridging header stuff all working as it should.

My issue is I am building a system menu in swift and am trying to call a method in my AppDelegate like this:

```
@objc func createMenuItem() {
    let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    let status = NSMenuItem(title: "System Status",
                            action: #selector(appDelegate.showSystemStatus(_:)),
                            keyEquivalent: "s")
    status.target=appDelegate.self
    statusItem.menu?.insertItem(status, at: 0)
}
```

I can't get the compiler to resolve `AppDelegate` on the first line of the func.

Xcode keeps telling me **"Cannot find type 'AppDelegate' in scope"**

[image]

My bridging header:

```
#ifndef Foo_Bridging_Header_h
#define Foo_Bridging_Header_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "uiframework/Utils.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#endif /* Foo_Bridging_Header_h */
```

My AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Foo-Swift.h"

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property SwiftUtils *utils;

- (void) checkForUpdates;
+ (void) showSystemStatus;

@end
```

Comment: convert AppDelegate to Swift, that will make the whole problem go away

Comment: Also I believe in Objective C, it's not `NSApplication.shared.delegate`, but rather `NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate`. And don't forget to `import UIKit`, cos this is where it's defined

Comment: @KirilS. It is `NSApplication.shared.delegate`. `sharedApplication` is the Objective-C property. `NSApplication` is AppKit.

Comment: @Willeke I might be wrong about accessing AppDelegate written in Objective-C - being a while. But your argument doesn't make much sense either. Of course it's an objective-c property (as `NSApplication` is written in objective C), but it has nothing to do with accessing it from Swift.

Comment: @KirilS. In Objective-C the property is called `sharedApplication`, in Swift the same property is called `shared`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand, *showSystemStatus* method is a class method (e.g. static) and you are trying to call this method from instance. Maybe it can be the root of your issue.

Following example should work for you:

```
let status = NSMenuItem(title: "System Status",
                action: #selector(AppDelegate.showSystemStatus),
                keyEquivalent: "s")
```

For preventing the cycling, you can move your implementation to another class and give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately that just moves the "Cannot find AppDelegate in scope" to the `action` line

Comment: Is it possible that you have created a cycle between AppDelegate and the Swift class that you are trying to make a call from?

Comment: Yes, I am confident that I do have that cycle. My AppDelegate calls this swift helper class to construct a menu on startup, but I want that menu to have an item that calls a static func in my AppDelegate

Comment: Best way to try this out is breaking the cycle first, basically two ways came to my mind; move out the implementation to another class or try using NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: @BurakAkkaş Why is the cycle a problem?

Comment: I don't understand the issue of the cycle being a problem but moving the code worked. It's fuglier this way but I get paid for making it work and not how pretty it is. So I did this: AppDelegate calls a swift guy who builds the menu and does other stuff I need. The menu's selector now goes to an `AppUtils.m` class which does the stuff I originally had in the AppDelegate. It works, just don't understand why I couldn't keep that code inside the AppDelegate without making my AppDelegate swift. @BurakAkkaş if you'll add `move implementation to another class` to your answer I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Well basically I tried to implement your solution and Xcode gave me an error about the cycle. That's basically what I have tried to inform you about. Glad to know at least your problem solved. I have edited my answer.